# How to map a SQLite database to another?

Tags: sqlite

I need to export the data of a SQLite database and import this data to another SQLite database. But the two databases have different schemas.

Does exist an open source tool that can help me doing that job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only opensource tool that i know is [opendbcopy](http://opendbcopy.sourceforge.net/) that i'm using for migrate from a database server to another and also for a similar kind of job that you want to do with SQLite but i've done it with PostgreSQL.

However opendbcopy is JDBC compliant and can connect to every database that have a JDBC driver, so you can try, also if the schema is not the same you can use the column mapping feature :

[image: opendbcopy]

In addition i know also a good commercial alternative (that is easier to use) that is ESF [Database Migration Toolkit](http://www.easyfrom.net/) .

Comment: ESF Database Migration Toolkit seems to make the job without too much configuration. Thank you for the info ;)